# Entity Relationship diagram: composite attributes vs entity

Tags: entity-relationship

So I have this small problem, I am trying to make an ER Diagram and I have a student. For the student entity it says:

**Record which school a student is in. A student must be attending one school. All schools contain at least one student. 
You are to record the following information schools: their names(must be unique), # of students attending, and the principal name.**

When I read this, it seems like "school" is a composite attribute or an entirely separate entity. Since it says "A student must be attending one school. All schools contain at least one student" should I make it an entity because I can't think of how to show this relationship via a composite attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, school is a separate entity. A composite attribute would be something like a 'name' which consists of a 'first name' and a 'last name'. The school only consists of school and student only consists of student in your example.

Comment: So even though it says record which school a student is in, I don't have to actually have the school attribute in the student entity since I am making school an entity.

Comment: Yes. Two different entities with a one to many relationship between them. I think you can guess who's one and who's many :)